# C# - Click inside the dataGridView for bigger picture

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView populated with data from an MS SQL database. The data also contains images with small dimensions (140x195).
Is there any way to click to the image and open a bigger picture?

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGQey.png)

Comment: Sure. Use the `CellClick` event; look at its parameters and test for e.ColumnIndex to be the right one. You will need to know how to find a larger image from e e.RowIndex and can then display it e.g. in a PictureBox which you can e.g. place at the cursor position and hide when no longer needed, or in a Form, which you can let the user close.. All pretty simple, once you know what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help TaW! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following code to show the picture to the pictureBox.

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
        int cardNo = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Number"].FormattedValue);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ImageFull FROM SS4 WHERE CardNo = '" + cardNo+"'", con);
        string img = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        pbCard.Image = Image.FromFile(img);
        con.Close();
    }
```

The path for the image is saved to the database.
I cannot find a way to show the picture to a new form instead to a pictureBox.

Comment: Glad to help! - You could avoid the extra trip to the db by selecting the paths into a column, which you hide. You could create a new sizeable  Form with a Picturebox and make it Dock=Fill and the pbox SizeMode=Zoom. You could open it a the beginning, keep the reference handy, hide it until needed; in theF ormClosing write; `private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.UserClosing) e.Cancel = true;
}` - Set the Image in the click and Show the Form2 again..